# Python Regex Picking "not include" word

Tags: python, regex, search, find, match

I am trying to find words in the string that do not contain any "a" characters. I wrote the code below but it does not work. How can I say to regex "do not include"? Can't I use "^" sign as "not"?

```
import re
string2 = "asfdba12312sssdr1 12şljş1 kf"
t = re.findall(r'([^a]\w*) | \w*[^a] ', string2 )
print(t)
```

The result of that code is `"['sfdba12312sssdr1', '12şljş1']"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a regex with word boundaries with a `re.UNICODE` flag:

```
r = re.compile(ur'\b[^\Wa]+\b', re.UNICODE)
```

The `\W` and `\b` will become Unicode aware then.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rT2sS4/1)

`[^\Wa]` matches any Unicode letter, digit or inderscore, but not `a`. Add a `re.I` flag to make it case-insensitive.

If you do not want to match words with digits, add `\d` to the char class: `[^\W\da]`.

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vTM17x):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b[^\Wa]+\b', re.UNICODE)
s = u"asfdba12312sssdr1 12şljş1 kf"
res = [x.encode('utf8') for x in p.findall(s)]
print(res)
```

Comment: the result is "re.compile('\\b[^\\Wa]+\\b')"

Answer (score 1):

`[^a]` is the single non-`a` character. `[^a]\w*` is a single non-`a` character followed by any number of word-characters. Note that a space is a non-`a` character, and word-characters can also include `a`...

The easiest and the most intuitive way to do this in Python is not using `re.findall` at all:

```
[word for word in string2.split() if not 'a' in word]
```

Comment: This code will treat `word1,` or `word2?!` as words (i.e. will include punctuation and symbols).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Good point. Demonstrates to OP the benefit of not using nonsense as your example, I suppose.

Comment: With `rx = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b', re.UNICODE)` you could go for
`words = [word for word in rx.findall(string2) if not 'a' in word]`.